# Is it safe to count on internal pointer from strtok_r?

Tags: c, strtok

In this sample program I use `strtok_r` to split a string into two tokens.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char buf[] = "Hello World!";
    char tok[] = " ";
    char *p;

    char *retStr = strtok_r(buf, tok, &p);
    printf("\"%s\" \"%s\"\n", retStr, p);
    return 0;
}
```

The output of this program is

```
"Hello" "World!"
```

According to the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok_r) the pointer `p` is used internally by `strtok_r` for re-entry purposes. Is it also safe to assume that it points to the rest of the string, as I am here?

Comment: It isn't explicitly specified, so I wouldn't rely on it. It could be used by an implementation to point to some special internal structure (though that's very unlikely; it would be difficult to clean it up).

Comment: A more realistic ambiguity would be whether it points to the latest token, or a space after the latest token, or variations on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not safe. The documentation says only that `strtok_r` uses the pointer for internal purposes and it should not be changed by you between `strtok_r` calls. It means that, though you observe now that it points to the rest of the string, it is kind of accident, and implementors of the library can change it - then your program stops working because of a change in external library. I would avoid such unnecessary dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Unless it specifically *says* you can count on it being something, than you can't.

Vagueness on the part of documentation about how something is used, allows teh developers to change how it's used between versions without it being a breaking change.  So, while what you are doing might work now, there's no guaruntee that it will work with the next release of teh library.